# ObservableQuery with this id doesn't exist: 1 when refetching data from useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, apollo

I was hoping to resolve this error that I continue to get. I am currently trying to gain a person's location before performing a refetch but continue to get this error within the refetch catch `ObservableQuery with this id doesn't exist: 1`. Was hoping for some enlightenment in regards to this error. Following, I show how I take my approach to getting the location before performing a refetch of data once Lat and Long as been discovered.

```
const PostsComponent = () => {
  const route = useCallback(useRoute(), []);
  const latitude = useSelector(state => state.session.latitude);
  const longitude = useSelector(state => state.session.longitude);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { data, loading, error, fetchMore } = useQuery(getAllPosts, 
        { variables: { 
              category: route.name.toLowerCase(), 
              seenPosts: [], 
              lat: latitude, 
              long: longitude }, 
          skip: true });

  useEffect(() => {
    let isSubscribed = true;
    if (!latitude && !longitude) {
      getLocation();
    }
    return () => (isSubscribed = false);
  }, [])

  const getLocation = async () => {
    const { status } = await Permissions.getAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
    if (status === 'granted') {
      const location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({ enableAccuracy: true, accuracy: Location.Accuracy.Lowest });
      fetchMore({
        variables: { category: route.name.toLowerCase(), seenPosts: [], lat: location.coords.latitude.toString(), long: location.coords.longitude.toString() },
        updateQuery: (prev, { fetchMoreResult}) => {
          console.log("THE UPDATE VALUE IS ", fetchMoreResult);
          return prev; 
      }).catch(err => console.log(err));
      dispatch(setLatAndLong({lat: location.coords.latitude, long: location.coords.longitude}));
    }
  }

 return <Text>HELLO WORLD</Text>
}
```